# OTRS Fatal Error

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu, otrs

hey i want to install otrs on an apache webserver with linux ubuntu.
i created a new database with the otrs web installer but then I get the message: `Can't open file /opt/otrs/Kernel/Config/Files/ZZZAAuto.pm.20881: Permission denied`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the apache server doesn´t have permissions on this file.

The solution was to start the otrs permissions script with:

```
cd /opt/otrs/bin
sudo ./otrs.SetPermissions.pl --otrs-user=otrs --otrs-group=otrs --web-user=www-data --web-group=www-data /opt/otrs
```

Answer (score 0):

> File permissions need to be adjusted to allow OTRS to read and write files:

`otrs.SetPermissions.pl [ --otrs-user= OTRS user, defaults to 'otrs' ] { --web-group= group of the web server user }`

Web server which runs as the OTRS user:

`shell> otrs/bin/otrs.SetPermissions.pl --web-user=otrs`

Webserver with wwwrun user (e. g. SUSE):

`shell> otrs/bin/otrs.SetPermissions.pl --web-group=wwwrun`

Webserver with apache user (e. g. Red Hat, CentOS):

`shell> otrs/bin/otrs.SetPermissions.pl --web-group=apache`

Webserver with www-data user (e. g. Debian, Ubuntu):

`shell> otrs/bin/otrs.SetPermissions.pl --web-group=www-data`